# CardAction button with type=invoke doesn't work in microsoft bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, artificial-intelligence, microsoft-teams

According to this document [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/botsmessages#action---invoke-new] we can use invoke in Hero card button but it giving me below error 
"ActionTypes does not contain a definition for invoke

Um using Microsoft.Bot.Builder 3.2.1

Can someone help me

[My code in this Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqrHk.png)

Comment: Did you see anywhere that option in ActionTypes class ? What do you want to do actually ?

Comment: Invoke is tell by someone in Microsoft (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2640). Actually um using ImBack but problem is if i use imback it show user what um sending. Exaample if button text is Cinnamon Red but the value is um sending is 3201 and um dnot want user see 3201 in the chat. Do you have any solution for it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Invoke action exists, but it is reserved for internal use.

> Your bot may receive an invoke activity that represents a request for it to perform a specific operation. The sender of an invoke activity typically expects the bot to acknowledge receipt via HTTP response. This activity type is reserved for internal use by the Microsoft Bot Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Update BotBuilder.  While I'm not sure the exact release, I believe you'll want 3.5.x.

Invoke does work as documented - it sends a payload of your choice back to the bot (like `postBack`), but does not display anything in the chat window like `imBack` or `postBack` would do.

Note that the `Activity` your bot receives is of type: `invoke`, not `message`, per the documentation.

Comment: Moe Can you please give me a sample code how it doing. Currently i do not have any ideea

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the "invoke" actions type was ever implemented. Can't find any record of it on the botbuilder github repository. Not for version 3.2.1 or newer version.

You can check it out yourself [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/botbuilder%403.2.1/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Connector/ActionTypes.cs)